# Azure DevOps secure file guids

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

In my ADO build pipline, I have a secure file download step. When we branch versions, we use powershell to do the heavy lifting with cloning build definitions and updating settings/info in the cloned pipeline.

One issue I've run into is that the [Secure File Download step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-secure-file?view=azure-devops) doesn't accept variables, and in the UI you can only select names of files that already exist, so we've had to manually update it after every new branch we create.

I've grabbed the definition task step in powershell (as $step) and was hoping I could set the `$step.inputs.fileInputs` to a variable I assign to something like `cert-$newVersion`, however it currently is set to a guid.

[image: Build Step settings]

Does anyone know if it possible to get the guid of secure files in ADO via the API or have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know if it possible to get the guid of secure files in ADO via the API or have a solution?

Yes. This API exists.

You could try to use the following Rest API:

```
Get https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/distributedtask/securefiles?api-version=6.1-preview.1
```

**Result:**

[image]

You could get the secure file GUID based on the file name.

Comment: is this API documented anywhere on the learn.microsoft.com site? I also see downstream, terraform azuredevops provider is waiting on proper docs? https://github.com/microsoft/terraform-provider-azuredevops/issues/615